# Merge "cifs" and "smb" tags

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[cifs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cifs) x7 and [smb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smb) x1. They [are the same thing](http://blog.varonis.com/the-difference-between-cifs-and-smb/).

> When people use either SMB or CIFS, are talking about the same exact thing.  The two are interchangeable not only in discussion, but also in application – i.e., a client speaking CIFS can talk to a server speaking SMB and vice versa.  Why?  Because CIFS is a form of SMB.

SMB has tag info, while cifs does not.

I know there are not a ton of questions tagged with either of these, but found them while looking at some tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done, thanks for catching this.

Comment: I also just found cyanogenmod x1045 and cyanogenmod-11 x89. Should I create a new "request" for that? we dont have tags for any other version of CM. And no synonyms either. could probably just merge cm-11 in to cm?

Comment: I second that (merge).

Comment: @RyanConrad: May want to weigh in here - http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1715/981